# full screen animated background

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I want to create a full-size background animating with a slow fade effect.
So far I have this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/mkzd9/2/)

html:

```
<img src="http://elegantthemes.com/preview/InStyle/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/s-1.jpg" />
<img src="http://elegantthemes.com/preview/InStyle/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/s-5.jpg" />
<img src="http://elegantthemes.com/preview/InStyle/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/s-3.jpg" />
```

css:

```
body, html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:black;
}
img{
position:absolute;
top:0;
display:none;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

js:

```
function test() {
$("img").each(function(index) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).delay(10000 * index).fadeIn(10000).fadeOut();
});
}
test();;
```

Also, the fade effect doesn't work in a way I want it really to work. Instead of fading in the new background and THEN removing the previous one, it fades in and fades out in the same time which means there is a moment where there is no background or it is barely visible, if you know what I mean.
So basically what I need to modify in this code is:

1. change a code slightly to remove the gap between changing slides, so it fades in, then remove the previous background, not both in the same time
2. This will be a background, not the image, so maybe there is a better way of applying this, possibly somehow using a  only. I don't want to affect any other items which will be placed later on this page.

thank you in advance

Comment: i know isn't you're question but you have this script for that, i use for all my project when i need background full size responsive, it's easy to config : http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/4CHse/1/

```
$('img').hide();
$('img').eq(0).show();

function anim() {
    $("#wrap img").first().appendTo('#wrap').fadeOut(1000);
    $("#wrap img").first().fadeIn(1000);    
    setTimeout(anim, 1500);
}
anim();
```

Comment: that works well thank you. let me implement it to my project and see how it goes. thanks a lot @yeyene

Comment: It actually works well, but there is one issue. On the beginning I have a plain black background. How can I fill it with the first image? It's not visible when you set the timing for 1000 but if you do it 7 seconds you wait that time before the first background appears. How to overcome this. This is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/RnqQL/216/

Comment: You want to show first image, right? check my update answer again.

Comment: it looks good on jsfiddle but unfortunately when I change time to  7 secs delay and 3 secs fading there is still a delay before the first img. here is the live version: http://test.captive-portal.com/bg

Comment: have you add this on doc ready? $('img').eq(0).show(); http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/4CHse/1/

Comment: Try... $(document).ready(function(){ // add scripts here and see.. });

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you suppose to use a jQuery Plugin

[here is a cycle2 demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/basic.php)